# Error: coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, prediction, error

I am trying to understand predictions from distributed lag no linear models. I use trial data from R and I run a glm model with crossbasis matrix from DLNM package. When I am trying to get the predictions I get this error:
Error in crosspred(crossbasis, model, cumul=TRUE)  :
coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix.
The code is:

```
crossbasis<-crossbasis(data$variable2,lag=2,argvar=list(knots=equalknots(data$variable2, df=3)),arglag=list(knots=logknots(2,df=4)))
model<-glm(variable1 ~ crossbasis + ns(Time, df=4*12),family=poisson, data)
predictions<- crosspred(crossbasis, model)
```

If I run the same code using lag=3 I have no error.
Why is that happen?

Answer (score 4):

You are specifying a function with 4df in the lag space (arglag), but that dimension is defined only as lag 0-2, therefore with 3 observations.
The model is overparameterized, and this results in perfectly correlated variables and unidentifiable coefficients that are set to NA.

Just simplify your model in the lag space and it will work.

Best
-Antonio Gasparrini

Comment: Thank you very much!